# Poisson Distribution with Limousines

Tags: probability

> A car company has two limousines that it hires out by the day. The number of requests per day has a Poisson distribution with mean 1.3 requests per day.
>
> If each limousine is to be equally used,on how many days in a period of 365 days would you expect a particular limousine to be in use?

I did $1.3/2 = 0.65$ per limousine, and $0.65*365 = 237.25$. The answer is $201$ days. How so?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of receiving no requests in a day (causing both limousines to *not* be used) is
$$\mathsf P(k=0)=\frac{1.3^0e^{-1.3}}{0!}=0.272531$$
The probability of receiving exactly one request in a day (causing a limousine to be used half the time) is 
$$\mathsf P(k=1)=\frac{1.3^1e^{-1.3}}{1!}=0.354291$$
If two or more requests are received in a day, both limousines will be used. Therefore the probability of a limousine being used for the day is
$$1-(0.272531+\tfrac12\cdot0.354291)=0.550322$$
Over 365 days, we expect a limousine to be used on $365\cdot0.550322=200.867$ days, which rounds to 201 days.